# Stable sets for gradient flow of functions with singularities

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, morse-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-analytic function, and let $F_t$ denote the gradient flow of $f$ with respect to some background metric. Suppose that $df = 0$ at a point $p$. In the situations I am interested in, the critical point will be contained in a critical submanifold $C$ which will be "generically Morse-Bott" in the sense that the Hessian in the normal direction will be nondegenerate *except* on a further submanifold $D \subset C$; assume $p \in D$.

We consider the *stable set*
$$
W^s(p) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \lim_{t \to \infty}F_t(x) = p\}.
$$
At a Morse-Bott critical point, this is known to be a smooth manifold of dimension equal to the Morse index, i.e. the number of negative eigenvalues of the Hessian.

I am interested in results which give a description of the stable set when the Hessian is degenerate (and not just in the Morse-Bott case). I am most interested in knowing if there are general structural descriptions (e.g. does the stable set always admit the structure of a stratified space?), and, assuming that ``dimension'' can be defined suitably, in results which tell you what the dimension of the stable set is. I'm having a hard time finding a discussion of this in the smooth dynamics literature (or elsewhere): it seems that at least in introductory texts, only the hyperbolic case is ever treated...